# Difference between “当…时”, “…的时候”, and “当…的时候”?

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between :

> “当…时”

and

> “…的时候”

and

> “当…的时候”

when referring to "when" in Chinese?

I have tried to look for an answer but I couldn't find a clear one. When should you use each option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> "当(~~~)时” is the shortened form of  “当(~~~)的时候"
>
> "(~~~)时” is the shortened form of  “(~~~)的时候"

1. “当(~~~)时” = “当(~~~)的时候” = "At the time when (~~~)"

   - *当 = at/ during*
   - *的时候 = the time when/ of*

Example:

"当(没有其他选择)时" = "当(没有其他选择)的时候" = "At the time when (there's no other choice)"

you can replace '当' with '在' and write "在(没有其他选择)时"

2. "(~~~)时” = "(~~~)的时候” = "when(~~~)"

Example:

"(没有其他选择)时" = "(没有其他选择)的时候" = "when (there is no other choice)"

Answer (score 1):

your  understanding  is  okay.

Abovementioned  example  is right.

“没有什么选择时，……”  is  the  common  sense  in  Chinese。